# Loop td content with vertical axis in table into special div format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with vertical axis (first column in each ) like that

```
<table id="tbl-hn">
<tr>
    <td>Title A</td><td>a1</td><td>...</td><td>a10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Title B</td><td>b1</td><td>...</td><td>b10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Title C</td><td>c1</td><td>...</td><td>c10</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can I loop all the content in this table like this:

```
<div class="content">
<div>
    <div>Title A:</div><div>a1</div>
    <div>Title B:</div><div>b1</div>
    <div>Title C:</div><div>c1</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Title A:</div><div>a...</div>
    <div>Title B:</div><div>b...</div>
    <div>Title C:</div><div>c...</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Title A:</div><div>a10</div>
    <div>Title B:</div><div>b10</div>
    <div>Title C:</div><div>c10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/yn6z9x0o/). This will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
            var title = ["Title A", "Title B", "Title C"];

            var alp= ["a", "b", "c"];

            var text = "";

            var i;
            var j;

            for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
                    {
                            text += title[i] + " " + alp[i] +""+ j + "<br>";
                    }
                    text+="<br>"
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. Just code is not enough.